# ocaml toplevel throws error unbounded module

Tags: ocaml

I installed OCAML and OPAM, then I installed libraries such as ocaml-http using OPAM. When I tried to open module Http_types, ocaml toplevel is throwing error unbounded module.

I tried to set CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH in **/home/ubuntu/.opam/opam-init/variables.sh**

old one generated during opam init:

CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/lib/stublibs; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
PERL5LIB=/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/lib/perl5:$PERL5LIB; export PERL5LIB;
OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/lib/toplevel; export OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH;
MANPATH=$MANPATH:/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/man; export MANPATH;
PATH=/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/bin:$PATH; export PATH;

I added CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/lib/stublibs:/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/lib; export CAML_LD_LIBRARY_PATH;

/home/ubuntu/.opam/4.01.0/lib is where all the new non-standard libraries are installed. But when i do opam init again newly added line will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load this library with a `#require` directive, something like this should work:

```
#use "topfind";;
#require "ocaml-http";;
```

Do not forget to actually type this `#` symbol.